# Is it possible to run a single VM on two bare mettal?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, hypervisor

I have two bare-metal machines with the following configuration:

**machine1**

```
CPU: 4 cores
ram: 16GB
HD: 200GB
```

**machine2**

```
cpu: 4 cores
ram: 16GB
HD: 200GB
```

is it possible to have a VM using these two bare-metal machines with the following configuration:

```
cpu: 8 cores
ram: 32GB (Approximate)
HD: 400GB (Approximate)
```

Sorry, if I asked vey naive question, I am very new to vertualization world.

**EDIT**

I am not trying to do this, just want to know the concept.

Comment: What hypervisor are you running?  Are you asking if you run the same VM on two different host machines at the same time?  Why do you want to do that? By the way, even if this was possible, your example configuration wouldn't actually be a valid configuration.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have a single VM using the combined resources of two hosts?

No

---

This isn't possible because the interconnects between two hosts are so much slower than the internal connections.

Even technologies like [VMware VMotion](https://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmotion_datasheet.pdf) (which allows "*seamless*" migration of virtual machines from one physical host to another) aren't quite there.

[image: vmotion diagram]

They claim to achieve "*Live migration of virtual machines without service interruption*" yet still have to spend some time syncing data during operation, before suspending the service for some period of time to do a final sync of the virtual machine state and memory - the linked document claims "*the entire process takes less than two seconds on a Gigabit Ethernet network*" (I suspect referring to the final suspend / sync / resume).

---

If you have multiple machines, then a better approach is to distribute the load:

- [Load Balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) - run the same service on multiple hosts, directing clients at the most suitable (local / unloaded / etc...)
- [Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) - break the task into multiple parts and distribute the parts

Comment: VMotion is as seamless as it can get, you can migrate the virtual machine you are using, to migrate the machine while connected to VCenter using the VSphere client and you will not notice any sort of transition.

Comment: As seamless as it can get yes, but you will notice _some_ "stutter" during the transition... Luckily that will be covered up by TCP retires, etc... so the user probably won't actually notice.